# Import pyspark error Pyspark with python 3.5.1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-3.5

Pyspark with python 2.7 works fine for me. 
I installed python 3.5.1 (installed from source)
I get this error when I run pyspark in terminal

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr 25 2016, 12:41:28) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pyspark
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 98, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 58, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
```

I tried `python 3.4.3` , that also works fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that zlib is actually there in your python install? It should be by default but strange things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the exact path to system python3.5.1 to "PYSPARK_PYTHON" in your .bashrc file?

```
 Welcome to
   ____              __
  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
   /_/  

Using Python version 3.6.1 (default, Jun 23 2017 16:20:09)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

This is what my PySpark prompt shows . Apache Spark verison is 2.1.1

P.S : I use Anaconda3 (Python 3.6.1) for my daily PySpark codes with my PYSPARK_DRIVER set to 'jupyter'

The Above Example is with my Default System Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Try it `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark` 
In case your problem persist probably you need to change your ~/.basrc

Answer (score 0):

before starting pyspark in shell type below command:
    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.5
(or)
    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.5

Answer (score 0):

Works for ME!

After install Python 3.5:

```
1. Install pip

    sudo apt-get install python<VERSION>-pip

2. Install notebook if this module is not installed

3. Install ipython

    sudo apt-get install ipython<VERSION> ipython<VERSION>-notebook

4. Install py4j it's not installed

5. Set environment variables
   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python<VERSION>
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython<VERSION>
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
   export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip

6. If necessary(and if it's installed)
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-<VERSION>-src.zip

7. Don't forget to save all this 'export' on ~/.bashrc

8. source ~/.bashrc

9. pyspark
```

Now if it's all ok a browser will be ran and a notebook will appear with 'python3' session available. This session already have an 'SparkSession' object and 'SparkContext' object available on 'spark' and 'sc' variables, respectively

Answer (score 0):

also try to install pyspark with pip3 version, and then set path os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3' in your code