# Py4JJavaError Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run the below code . When i am running `pyspark` in cmd it is running fine.

```
    import pyspark

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('Test').getOrCreate()

print("spark session has been created")

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3])
print(rdd.first())
```

The session is created but in parallelize part i am getting the error i am running this code in my jupyter notebook

Full Trace Error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4515e949bc62> in <module>
      7 
      8 rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3])
----> 9 print(rdd.first())
     10 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in first(self)
   1586         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1587         """
-> 1588         rs = self.take(1)
   1589         if rs:
   1590             return rs[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1566 
   1567             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1568             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1569 
   1570             items += res

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1225         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1226         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1227         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1228         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1229 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: What python version/executable are you using?

Comment: python 3.8.8  i am using

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834732/import-pyspark-error-pyspark-with-python-3-5-1

Comment: The link you have provided not able to solve the issue . i dont understand why the same code is running through cmd